# WPF & XAML problem

Tags: wpf, xaml, inkcanvas

Im new in WPF & Xaml 
I dont know how to anchor how to dock...
On this screen gray is statusBar is docked but grid and menu is not all components are in canvas. 
This is XAML

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Canvas>
        <StackPanel Height="40" Width="624" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Menu Height="39" Margin="1,0,0,0">
                <Menu.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF6F6F6" Offset="0.25"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEAE8E8" Offset="0.25"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCD9D9" Offset="0.8"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Menu.Background>
            </Menu>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="356" Canvas.Top="44" Width="161" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Expander Header="Expander" Height="107">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="360" Canvas.Left="161" Canvas.Top="40" Width="463">
            <DataGrid Height="361"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
    <StackPanel Height="40" Margin="-1,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <StatusBar Height="40" Background="#FF897676"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Where do you want the grid and menu to be located on the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want these things to go in a `Canvas`. I'm not sure I've ever used a `Canvas` in WPF.

`DockPanel` is your friend, and this is how it works:

- Each control in the `DockPanel` gets a `DockPanel.Dock` attached property : Left, Top, Right, or Bottom
- What, no Fill? This is important: You can have one control fill up available space, and that will be the *last control declared in the `DockPanel`*. So, even if you want the "fill" control to be at the very top, you make it the last item in the `DockPanel` and set `DockPanel.Dock="Top"`.
- Other than the last, "fill" item, others which have the same dock setting will be docked in the order in which they were declared.

At its most basic, `DockPanel` can be used just like `StackPanel` except it will fill available space.

Comment: @user There is no anchor. There are a bunch of different panel types, each with its own way of laying out its children. You'll just need to familiarize yourself with them (DockPanel, StackPanel, Grid, FlowLayoutPanel, etc.) and learn to apply the right one for the right effect.